Is a custom "udecimal" (positive only decimal" struct a terrible idea?
After writing my 10,000th check to ensure a decimal argument is greater than or equal to zero, I wondered:
Wouldn't it be easier to create a custom decimal struct that enforces this rule, much like uint?
After looking at the Decimal.cs source, I'm having second guesses.
There's a lot going on in there, and it's not hard to imagine baking this into an application - and then finding some critical problem.
Are there any libraries out there that have already done this?
Or, are there reasons this is a terrible idea?

New type is just one possibility to solve issues. Consider to try codereview and software engineering, you may get more (better?) ideas. Your question is currently lacking to present the issue, where are such checks, are they many, etc.

I contend that this question is not opinion-based and should not be closed. There are many possible objective reasons - serialization, underlying framework issues, underlying  framework architecture, etc. - that could (or could not) make this approach problematic, which is why I'm asking. This clearly is not an application design architecture question.

Well, with a help of generic math you can try implementing UDecimal based on Decimal if you like:
using System.Numerics;

...

public struct UDecimal 
    : IAdditionOperators<UDecimal, UDecimal, UDecimal>,    // We can add UDecimals
      ISubtractionOperators<UDecimal, UDecimal, UDecimal>  // We can subtract UDecimals etc.
{
    private readonly decimal _value;

    public UDecimal(decimal value)
    {
        ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative(value);

        _value = value;
    }

    public static UDecimal operator +(UDecimal left, UDecimal right) => 
        new UDecimal(left._value + right._value);

    public static UDecimal operator -(UDecimal left, UDecimal right) => 
        new UDecimal(left._value - right._value);

    ...
}

There are many interfaces you should implement, but almost all the methods are evident oneliners.
However, I suggest implementing your custom class, say
public struct Price {
  public decimal Value {get;}

  public Price(decimal value) {
    // Note some extra validation
    if (value < 0 || value > 1_000_000)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));

    Value = value;
  }

  // Some extra property etc. 
  public decimal Vat => Value * 0.20M;
}


Thanks - both options I've started down at on point or another... but I got concerned when seeing constructors/methods/properties in Decimal.cs like "Decimal(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)", "IAdditiveIdentity<decimal, decimal>.AdditiveIdentity", etc. Suggested that I'm in way over my head with how things like that are used, how I should implement them, or that there could be much bigger resulting issues down the road.

@Sean: You can well skip some interfaces (like ISerializable which is in fact obsolete https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0051). If you really want serialization you should implement JsonConverter<UDecimal>

Alright, thanks! I suppose my hangup is that I don't even know if I want things like that, or how it's used (or not used) deeper in the framework. Just trying to avoid innocently walking into a landmine by getting too fancy (been there enough times).

I would not try to implement a new numeric type but instead implement the logic on a higher level. Say, you have a bank account class. Then you can ensure that withdrawals don't exceed the balance.
public class BankAccount
{
    public BankAccount()
    {
    }

    public BankAccount(decimal balance)
    {
        if (balance < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Initial balance must not be negative");
        }
        Balance = balance;
    }

    public decimal Balance { get; private set; }

    public void Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Amount must be positive");
        }
        Balance += amount;
    }

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Amount must be positive");
        }
        if (amount > Balance) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Balance too small for this withdrawal.");
        }
        Balance -= amount;
    }
}


Certainly the ideal solution for most people reading this. In my case, almost the entire (tens of thousands) application is constantly dealing with decimals that often can't be negative or sometimes can't be zero (lots of statistics, prices, price distances, etc).  I'm basically using this approach right now, but that's the pain point, since almost every class needs to implement it.
